# How can I wipe my Ultrabook that is running 11.10 (No CD Drive, just USB)

Tags: 11.10, usb

The links I have found refer to CD's.

Is there a recommended or good way to do this all from a USB Drive.

I need to do a wipe to clear saved data, i.e. a 'write' clean.

Then I'll reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a bootable usb with the downloaded linux Ubuntu iso image and then boot it.

Click on Try Ubuntu instead of install ubuntu.

You will enter the LIVE UBUNTU version(not installed.just running live for you to experience ubuntu)

In the menu there,start Gparted and format the drive using Gparted.

then you can install with the install ubuntu icon in the launcher

Comment: This was the method that worked for me.

Comment: Thats gr8..!! :) happy it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Darik's Boot and Nuke](http://www.dban.org/)!

Download the [ISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.2.6/dban-2.2.6_i586.iso/download), and then use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make a bootable flash drive from the ISO.

To install Unetbootin:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

*About DBAN:*

> Darik's Boot and Nuke ("DBAN") is a self-contained boot disk that
>   securely wipes the hard disks of most computers. DBAN will
>   automatically and completely delete the contents of any hard disk that
>   it can detect, which makes it an appropriate utility for bulk or
>   emergency data destruction. DBAN is a means of ensuring due diligence
>   in computer recycling, a way of preventing identity theft if you want
>   to sell a computer, and a good way to totally clean a Microsoft
>   Windows installation of viruses and spyware.